# WPF: How to reference other controls within trigger Property property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a WPF page. Page has some content, but the last child component of page's root layout is a user control that I have created. It looks like this:

```
<UserControl DataContext=UserControlViewModel>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid 
      Name="grid" 
      Visibility="{Binding IsOn, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
    <!-- Border to dim everything behind my user control -->
    <Border Background="#000000" Opacity="0.4" />
    <!-- The following border is red and holds the content -->
    <Border 
        Width="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=ActualWidth}" 
        Height="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=ActualHeight}" 
        Margin="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=Margin}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=HorizontalAlignment}" 
        VerticalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=VerticalAlignment}" 
        Background="Red">
      <TextBlock 
          Name="txt"
          Width="200" 
          Height="100" 
          Margin="20" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Text="This is my super awesome message!" />
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

By default, the `IsOn` property of the `UserControlViewModel` object is set to `false`, i.e. the user control is not visible. I have implemented some logic that changes this property to `true` and then the user control is displayed in front of all other components which are dimmed. This works well.

Now, I want to create a fade effect animation which would dim the components that are behind the user control once it becomes visible. Next, I want to make my red border that holds the content to fade in from the left hand side, so moving + fade.

Let's start with the fade effect first. I wrote this style to the `Border` that is supposed to do the dimming of background components:

```
<UserControl DataContext=UserControlViewModel>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid 
      Name="grid"
      Visibility="{Binding IsOn, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
    <!-- Border to dim everything behind my user control -->
    <Border Background="#000000" Opacity="0.4">
      <!-- The following style is new code -->
      <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="{Binding ElementName=grid, Visibility}" Value="Visible">
              <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                        From="0.0" 
                        To="0.4" 
                        Duration="0:0:1" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
              </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Border.Style>
    </Border>
    ...
```

But there's the problem: I cannot set the binding on the trigger `Property`, because it is not a dependency property. I need a way to tell my trigger to fire once the `grid` has got the `Visibility` property set to `Visible`. Please help and thank you!

Second problem is, I don't know how to do the moving of the red border, so I need help around some scale transformations as well, I guess... Thanks once again!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try replacing the following line:

Original:

```
<Trigger Property="{Binding ElementName=grid, Visibility}" Value="Visible">
```

Replacement:

```
<DataTrigger Binding={Binding Visibility, ElementName=grid} Value="Visibile">
```

Comment: @myermian: I am not quite sure what you've meant. Could you explain it in a few more sentences please? Thanks.

Comment: @Boris: Looking at your code again, I don't see a Trigger.ExitActions. I think you need that so it can repeat.

Comment: @myermian: I added DataTrigger.ExitActions. It works properly now. But there's a problem again. I wanted to create a fade animation inside ExitActions, but it doesn't work. It just reverts the opacity to the original 0 value. My animation gradually returns this value, for one whole second (inverted to the one shown in the question body). Where am I mistaking?

Comment: I think I know the answer now. There is a button on the user control which changes the value of the `IsOn` property of the `UserControlViewModel` to `false`. This is followed by immediate closing, i.e. hiding of the user control, so there is no time for the animation to take place. I need to rethink the logic of this user control.